# Re-adding yeast after a blow off

Tags: first-time-brewer, stuck-fermentation, blow-off

I am a first time shiner. I had a blow-off this morning, I'm making shine. I use a plastic bucket with a screw-on air tight lid and an airlock. The pressure blew the screw-on lid off. After cleaning up and adding a blow-off hose, I noticed that the mash is no longer bubbling at all. And, that beautiful krausen I had is all but forgotten. Should I re-add yeast?

I used 5 gallons water, 5 pounds of cornmeal and about 10 pounds of sugar. Then I used TURBO CLASSIC YEAST.

Answer (score 3):

What blew out is just the krausen while it has a lot of great yeast in it, there should be plenty left to complete fermentation.

Just a note.
Cornmeal needs a cereal mash to expose starches and then enzymes from grain or adding them directly to get fermentable sugars on a mash. If this wasn't done then all that fermented was the 10lb of sugar, so keep that in mind when taking gravity readings.

Comment: To add on, the unconverted corn meal may provide food for contaminations.

Comment: @DennyConn indeed. But if it's hypothetically being distilled it wouldn't matter much.

Comment: yes, if that's the purpose.  Since this group is about homebrewing I didn't think of that.